# Style for nested Text is not working react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text>First</Text>
          <Text style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>Second</Text>
          <Text>Third</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ECF0F1"
  }
});
```

As you can see, we have nested `<Text>` components. The problem is some style props such as `borderBottomWidth` - `marginVertical` - `width` is NOT working for the nested components!

Any idea for solving this issue?

> Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the (width, marginVertical) are not working but I know that you should specify the (borderStyle=solid, borderColor) so that you can see it.I think that's the problem, hope it helped.
But I should say that it might not be it cause I came across your question by trying to ask one, and for me all the styles did not work, not only that but it's raising an error and it does not run at all, this strange behavior only happen to Text component whether nested or not.